# Unable to insert new event in Google Calendar via API

Tags: c#, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I am using Google Calendar v3, OAuth2 and I manage to login, query event feeds but I cannot insert a new event via api. The calendar is public and shared. Here is my sample code:

```
AtomEntry entry = new AtomEntry();
AtomPerson author = new AtomPerson(AtomPersonType.Author);
author.Name = "xx";    author.Email = "xx@yahoo.com";
entry.Authors.Add(author);    entry.Title.Text = "Test";
entry.Content.Content = "Test";
calname = "678546u3ua4e1cgc2g1ugku1kg@group.calendar.google.com";
feedUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{0}/events";
Uri postUri = new Uri(string.Format(feedUrl,calname));
AtomEntry insertedEntry = CalService.Insert(postUri, entry);
```

I get this error:

```
[WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.]
   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +6542104
   Google.GData.Client.GDataRequest.Execute() +136

[GDataRequestException: Execution of request failed: https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/678546u3ua4e1cgc2g1ugku1kg@group.calendar.google.com/events]
Can you please provide a working C# sample with all inclusive instructions on how to insert events from a web application after the user has given permission to use their calendar? Thanks!
```

Comment: Are you using service account? if yes, did you follow the steps for domain wide delegation https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation mentioned in this link

Answer (score 0):

Check the scopes that you have requested for your OAuth 2.0 access token. For writing to Calendars you need a different permission than for reading only. See: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth. You should make sure you request and get the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar` from the Calendar owner.